# 14.10 upgrade failed now no user profiles and screen config is hosed

Tags: upgrade

Completed download of 14.10 overnight. Stated that the upgrade failed. Just sat for an hour after that message and I was not able to check anything as nothing seemed to work, no keyboard, no mouse, etc. Did a hard reboot as only way to move forward. That was a MISTAKE as now nothing, the screen configuration is hosed. Only thing that happens is a message to run graphics in low mode or fix. When try to fix nothing seems to work. Rebooted and selected TTY boot version to try to see what had failed. Seems not to be able to find any user profiles and when asked for root password to proceed fails. When entering password on first and all subsequent keystrokes immediately states invalid password, enter password of Control-D; neither works...

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live-CD or USB, take a look at the files of your hard drive after mounting the corresponding partition.

Maybe the password file got messed up, but from what you described, much more went wrong with your upgrade, so reinstalling (if that is an option) might save you hours of troubleshooting.